# Is square of probability $p^2$ is less than probability $p$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, probability, statistics

suppose we have $N$ possible states in system. There is a probability $p_n$ that system is in state $|n\rangle$, and the sum of all probabilities is one. Is there any general rule in math or physics for which the squared probability $p_n^2$ is less than probability $p_n$?

Comment: $x^{2} < x$ for $0 < x < 1$

Comment: Honestly, this is a math question, not much so physics

Comment: If $p_n$ really is a mathematical probability, then sure, there is such a rule (but it's "less than or equal to"). Because this is tagged quantum-mechanics, however, I feel compelled to ask: are you sure the original context of $p_n$ does not define it as some quantum-mechanical _quasiprobability,_ which might be outside the interval $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2):

The sum $\sum_n p_n^2 \le \sum_n p_n$ with the equality only being if $p_n = \delta_{nk}$ for some $k$.  This follows because $p_n \in [0, 1]$ (and hence $p_n^2 \le p_n$) and $\sum_n p_n = 1$.